# error noCamerasAvailable, which is only on iPhone <8+ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

i have a strange issue which I can notice only on devices older than iPhone 8+,
I don't know how can I fix that but error message is very simple 'noCamerasAvailable,'
Everything with permissions should be okay cause it works on my iPhone XS Max and my friend's iPhone X. That is my simply code to display camera view

```
cameraController.prepare {(error) in
             if let error = error {
                 print("Camera error:")
                 print(error)
             }

             try? self.cameraController.displayPreview(on: self.view)
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed I had to replace this

```
let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
```

to this

```
let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
```